# Call code-behind function from java script in c#

Tags: asp.net

Is it even possible? To call a code-behind c# function from java script in a visual web part?
It is a complex function so converting all codes to client side is not an option. 
I want the logic that is there in this function to happen without a page refresh.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use j Query ajax to call server side method and get the response to be used in java script. 
This article has simple and good example to show what you need to do.

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetDate()
  {
    return DateTime.Now.ToString();
  }
}
```

Java script

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting here.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We can call a method in codebehind from the JQuery AJAX call and depending upon the status whether it is error or success the corresponding method will be executed.

```
   function MyMethod() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CodeBehind.aspx/ClearData",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    data: '',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        closePopUpwindow1();
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus) {
        closePopUpwindow2();
    }
});}

    [WebMethod]
   public static void ClearData(){
 Page.SetGridSessionData(gridID, null);
}
```

If the server side method is successfully executed then closePopUpwindow1 method is executed else closePopUpwindow2 method will be executed.